# open map from a topological space whose connected components aren't open to a connected space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a connected topological space, and $Y$ a space which is not the disjoint union (as topological spaces) of its connected components (ie, the connected components of $Y$ are not all open). Can there exist an open continuous surjective map $Y\rightarrow X$ with finite fibers?

Motivation: I want to argue that any surjective etale map of schemes $Y\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is a connected scheme must have $Y$ be the disjoint union of its connected components.

EDIT: By disjoint union (as topological spaces), I mean the coproduct in the category of topological spaces, sometimes denoted as the "topological sum".

Comment: Your condition on $Y$ in the main text is not the same as that listed in the title - the former is never satisfied.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein If $Y$ is an infinite profinite space (a compact hausdorff totally disconnected space), then since it is not a discrete space, it is not the disjoint union of its connected components (which are just the singletons). The key being **disjoint union**. If $A,B$ are spaces, then each of $A$ and $B$ is **open** in $A\sqcup B$.

Comment: Oh you mean disjoint union **as a topology**, not as a set? That was not clear at all; you had me quite baffled for a minute there.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I'm sorry if that was confusing. In general whenever I talk about objects of a certain category, then by default any constructions I mention will take place in that category. (If I wanted a disjoint union of sets, then I would specify that it were a disjoint union *as sets*)

Comment: It's just amusing to me that you thought it was helpful to emphasize **disjoint union**.

Comment: @oxeimon: Some of us don’t think in category-theoretic terms. I’m a set-theoretic topologist; for me the default is a disjoint union as sets, and every space is the disjoint union of its connected components, since the latter partition the space. I now understand what you’re asking, but I certainly would not have done without the comments.

Comment: Consider the term **topological sum** when you mean a space which is the coproduct of other spaces in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Another term I like for this concept is the "discrete union"; it captures the idea using special terminology adapted to the category. While I appreciate thinking in categorical terms, I find it much less confusing to use special terminology adapted to the category. Just as an example, we just don't use "morphisms" when we don't have to: "continuous functions" in topology; "homomorphisms" in groups or rings; "linear maps" in vector spaces; and so on.

Comment: Amended my answer to include a space Y and a connected space X or which such a map does exist.

Answer (score 5):

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for (I don't know anything about schemes) but there is at least one Y for which no such map exists for any connected X.

Let $Y = \{1/2,1/3,...,0\}$ equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$. The connected components of this space are the singletons, and all of them are open except for $\{0\}$.

Assume we have an open, continuous, surjective map $f:Y \to X$ with finite fibers. We will show that X is necessarily disconnected.

Since $f$ is an open map with finite fibers, the set $f(Y - \{0\})$ is infinite and all of its points are open. If $f(Y - \{0\}) = X$ then X is disconnected and we are done.

Assume $f(Y - \{0\}) \neq X$. Since f is finite-to-one there must be a largest k such that $f(1/2) = f(1/k)$. Then $f(\{1/(k+1),1/(k+2),...,0\})$ is an open set which contains $f(0)$ but does not contain $f(1/2)$. In fact the complement of $f(\{1/(k+1),1/(k+2),...,0\})$ is a finite number of points, all of which are open in X. Therefore X is disconnected.

On the flip side, there is a space Y and a connected space X for which such a map does exist.

Let $Y = \{(0,1/n) \times \{1-1/n\}: n \geq 1\} \cup \{(0,1)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X$ be the half open interval $[0,1) \times \{0\}$. Then the projection map from $Y$ to $X$ is an open, continuous, surjective map with finite fibers.

Comment: Nice! Notation's a bit confusing though; I think you want to say $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \ge 1}  \big((0,1/n) \times \{1-1/n\}\big)$ in place of $\{(0,1/n) \times \{1-1/n\}: n \geq 1\}$. It doesn't help that we use the same notation for intervals and for ordered pairs...